# Saving and restoring Date in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd

I run a command script that saves date to text file.

```
echo %date% > date.txt
```

Only problem this command saves the day in text file like so

```
Sun 13/08/2017
```

When it starts the service, I have a command to change date back

```
date < date.txt
```

I get an error 
The system cannot accept the date entered.

It needs to show

```
13/08/2017
```

For this command to work

```
date < date.txt
```

I have someone gave me this command

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do echo %i > date.txt
```

it removes the day, it runs by itself.
but to run with a script it closes after it executes,
it doesnt seem to run with script.

I have other computers , I use this script and after windows update

It fixes issue; the windows update on other computer removes the day.

This computer had all windows update , but the day still displays
When you type `<date>` in cmd

Comment: use code formatting. It makes your code formatted and readable ;)

Comment: I would use something else for this, for example Windows scripting host or powershell, depending on which Windows versions you need to support

Comment: i never used powershell, its running on Windows pro x64

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is using string substitution and write into the text file only the last 10 characters of the region dependent date string of built-in environment variable **DATE** by using this code:

```
>date.txt echo %DATE:~-10%
```

Avoid a space character before redirection operator `>` on writing a text with `echo` into a file as this space character is written as trailing space also into the file.

Sometimes it is unsafe to use `echo %VariableText%>OutputFile.txt` because of the variable text could end with a number in range 1 to 9 which would result in execution of the command line with `1>` to `9>` which means redirect handle 1 to 9 to the file instead of writing the number `1` to `9` to the file. In such cases it is advisable to specify the redirection to file at beginning of the command line before command `echo` as done on the command line above.

It would be also possible to use this code to save the date in format `DD/MM/YYYY` into the ANSI encoded text file `date.txt`.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /Value') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
>date.txt echo %LocalDateTime:~6,2%/%LocalDateTime:~4,2%/%LocalDateTime:~0,4%
```

This code has the advantage of being independent on which region is set for the current user because the date and time string output by **WMIC** has always the same format. Run in a command prompt window `wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /Value` to see the UTF-16 encoded output of **WMIC** processed by command **FOR** line be line. The disadvantage is that this code is slower.

On setting the date back with using command **DATE** the region dependent date format must be known.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).